# What is the iOS 4.2 (and up) equivalent of Android's RecognitionListener?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios-4.2

The Android SDK has an API that lets you access Google Voice Search [directly](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/package-summary.html), not having to go through its well known [user interface implementation](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.voicesearch&hl=en).

A centerpiece in that API is the [RecognitionListener interface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognitionListener.html).

Is there an equivalent to this in iOS 4.2 (and up)?

If so, what term should I be searching for in the iOS SDK?

Comment: I don't believe there is one, in iOS if the user enters voice commands their controlled by the OS and I don't believe there is a public API for tapping into Siri or anything.

Comment: @MDT Thanks +1. I know there are 3rd party APIs for that, like [Nuance's](http://dragonmobile.nuancemobiledeveloper.com/public/index.php?task=home) or [Creaceed's](http://www.creaceed.com/ceedvocalsdk/), so I was hoping Google has one too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you can get to speech recognition is by using the [UIDictationPhrase](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidictationphrase), which is a part of the [UITextInput Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinput). However bear in mind that this API is available since iOS 5.1.

Comment: Thanks +1 for your answer. It's good to know that Apple now provides a built-in support for SR, but what about all the millions of people out there who only own an iPhone 4? See my comment above regarding 3rd party APIs. Does Google have one for the iPhone?

Comment: I'm afraid that Google does not provide any official means of using Google Search Voice on the iOS. I've heard of people who are using the API for Chrome, but that's not document anywhere so I'd guess Google wouldn't be very happy if they'd discover you're using it.